# xpath extract /text() returns empty using scrapy shell

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I need help with the following:

In a scrapy shell and trying to return the text of and xpath expression.
When I use the `/text()` method on the xpath I get nothing back. When I use the expression without it I get the data with the href. I can't understand why `/text()` doesn't work?

Url is "https://matchstat.com/tennis/all-upcoming-matches"

xpath without `/text()`

```
In [71]: response.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'player-
name')]").extract()[0]

Out[71]: '<td class="player-name"> <href="https://matchstat.com/tennis/player/H%20Kontinen%20%2F%20J%20Peers">  H Kontinen / J Peers </a>   (FIN/AUS)   <span class="badge">1</span>  </td>'
```

adding /text()

```
In [70]: response.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'player-
name')]/text()").extract()[0]

Out[70]: ' '
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The first xpath expression returns a list of Elements. You get the first item of this list which is a single `<td>` Element.

The second xpath expression returns a list of children text nodes of the the same `<td>` Elements. You get the fist child which is a single space: the one between the `<td class="player-name">` and `<href...>`. (It should be `<a href=...`).

Note: you are confused because the returned Element in the first case is printed as a string. But this is an Element with children: A text mode ' ', a `a` Element with a child text node "  H Kontinen / J Peers ", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found two solutions that give the returned the text in between the href

1.
using a dot at the start of the expression

```
response.xpath(".//td[contains(@class,'player-name')]").extract()[0]
```

2.
Adding the extra anchor tag at the end of the expression before text method

```
response.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'player-name')]/a/text()").extract()[0]
```